# ORACLE error while dbstart command

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I'm trying to start up Oracle DB with `startup` command. 
But error occurred while startup.

```
dbstart[80]: test: argument expected
Failed to auto-start Oracle Net Listene using /bin/tnslsnr
touch: $ORACLE_HOME/startup.log cannot create
chmod: $ORACLE_HOME/startup.log: No such file or directory
Processing Database instance "$ORACLE_SID": log file $ORACLE_HOME/startup.log
No such file or directory
dbstart[350]: $ORACLE_HOME/startup.log: cannot create
```

How can I fix it?  Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production is running under AIX.

Comment: have you changed any permissions lately?  Looks like a permissions error to me.

Comment: Looks like your environment's not set up/being set up  properly

Comment: `$ORACLE_HOME` probably isn't set & it's trying to write to `/`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue. The reason, why it has happened was the invalid entry in the `/etc/oratab`.

As `dbstart` script suggests, to configure, update `/etc/oratab` with instances that need to be started up. The entries are of the form:

```
$ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y|W>:
```

An example entry:

```
main:/usr/lib/oracle/emagent_10g:Y
```

Comment: I think you are right. `touch: $ORACLE_HOME/startup.log cannot create` shows that he really wants to use '$ORACLE_HOME' as ORACLE_HOME. nd he gets this value from /etc/oratab

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using a `dbstart` script to start your database.

In your `dbstart` script, change the value of `ORACLE_HOME_LISTENER`:

```
ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER=$ORACLE_HOME;
```

Comment: why should one change the Oracle dbstart script. Is there a bug in the script? Is this upon the advice of Oracle to do so?

Comment: This will not help. The problem is almost certainly that $ORACLE_HOME is not defined correctly.

Comment: you can see at your user bash profile.
or do 
export $ORACLE_HOME to correct oracle home location